# RavenDB : Storage Size Problems

Tags: ravendb

I'm doing some testing with RavenDB to store data based on an iphone application. The application is going to send up a string of 5 GPS coordinates with a GUID for the key. I'm seeing in RavenDB that each document is around 664-668 bytes. That's HUGE for 10 decimals and a guid. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I noticed the size was extraordinarily large when a million records was over a gig on disk. By my calculations it should be much smaller. Purely based on the data sizes shouldn't the document be around 100 bytes? And given that the document database has the object schema built in let's say double that to 200 bytes. Given that calculation the database should be about two hundred megs with 1 million records. But it's ten times larger. Can someone help me where I've gone wrong with the math here?

(Got a friend to check my math and I was off by a bit - numbers updated)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As a general principal, NoSQL databases aren't optimized for disk space.  That's the kind of traditional requirement of an RDBMS.  Often with NoSQL, you will *choose* to store the data in duplicate or triplicate for various reasons.

Specifically with RavenDB, each document is in JSON format, so you have some overhead there.  However, it is actually persisted on disk in BSON format, saving you some bytes.  This implementation detail is obscured from the client.  Also, every document has two streams - the main document content, and the associated metadata.  This is very powerful, but does take up additional disk space.  Both the document and the metadata are kept in BSON format in the ESENT backed document store.

Then you need to consider how you will access the data.  Any static indexes you create, and any dynamic indexes you ask Raven to create for you via its LINQ API will have the data copied into the index store.  This is a separate store implemented with Lucene.net using their proprietary index file format.  You need to take this into consideration if you are estimating disk space requirements.  (BTW - you would also have this concern with indexes in an RDBMS solution)

If you are super concerned about optimizing every byte of disk space, perhaps NoSQL solutions aren't for you.  Just about every product on the market has these types of overhead.  But keep in mind that disk space is cheap today.  Relational databases optimized for disk space because storage was very expensive when they were invented.  The world has changed, and NoSQL solutions embrace that.

Comment: If the database is hosted in the cloud, for example on RavenHQ or CloudBird, disk space consumption becomes relevant again because they will charge you more for bigger space.